# Jquery $.get to read header status on error

Tags: jquery, api, rest, jqxhr

I'm writing a REST api. It returns a header status 400 on error.

However, on the AJAX side, I couldn't get the jqxhr object returned.

```
$.get('site.php', function(data, status, jqxhr) function(data) {
    //...
}).error(console.log(jqxhr));
```

it returns `Uncaught ReferenceError: jqxhr is not defined`.
In inspector console, its showing 400 (Bad Request) for the get request.

How do I get the text Bad Request?

I could return the text error within data by passing it in header status 200, but that's not the right approach am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `error` function wants a callback function but you're executing `console.log(jqxhr)` and trying to hand its return value to `error` as the callback, that's where you're "jqxhr is not defined" error comes from.

You want something like this:

```
$.get('site.php', function(data, status, jqxhr) function(data) {
    //...
}).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Do something interesting.
});
```

You should also be using `fail` instead of `error` as [`error` is going away](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR):

> **Deprecation Notice:** The `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and `jqXHR.complete()` callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use `jqXHR.done()`, `jqXHR.fail()`, and `jqXHR.always()` instead.

Comment: perfect answer. and thanks for highlighting the use of .done() .fail() and .always() too.